# confused by testthat and skip_on_cran()

Tags: r, devtools, cran, testthat

**tl;dr** I want to run `devtools::test()` on a package and have it skip tests etc. *as though it were running on CRAN*, but I can't  figure out how.

As I understand it, `testthat::skip_on_cran()` checks for the environment variable `NOT_CRAN`, which should be set to a value of "true" if the tests are *not* being run on CRAN (to back this up, the underlying test function `testthat:::on_cran()` is equal to

```r
!identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN"), "true")
```

I am trying to use `skip_on_cran()` to skip some tests. I want to confirm that these tests will **actually be skipped on CRAN**. I have a line

```r
cat("ON CRAN:", testthat:::on_cran(), "\n")
```

in my test file so that I can see what R/`testthat` thinks is going on.

The environment variables get set the way I want (i.e., the output includes `ON CRAN: FALSE`)/the tests get skipped properly)  if I use

```r
source([testfile], echo = TRUE)
```

(i.e., without doing anything special to set or unset the `NOT_CRAN` environment variable beforehand) or

```r
withr::with_envvar(c(NOT_CRAN = "false"), 
    devtools::test_active_file("tests/testthat/test-bootMer.R"))
```

(if I run `test_active_file()` without wrapping it, I get `ON CRAN: FALSE`).

However, I don't see a way to run all the tests (via `devtools::test()`) in a similar way. In other words, **I can't figure out how to run `devtools::test()` in "ON CRAN" mode**.  `test()` doesn't have an explicit argument for this (it has `...` which is "additional arguments passed to wrapped functions", but I can't see anything relevant digging downward), and using `withr::with_envvar()` doesn't seem to help. `devtools::check()` *does* have an explicit `env_vars` argument, but I would like to be able to run the tests without going through the whole package check procedure ...

I'm sorry this isn't fully reproducible; if requested I can try to build a minimal package that will display the behaviour ...

Comment: sounds pretty much like [Skip tests on CRAN, but run locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166288/skip-tests-on-cran-but-run-locally), no?

Comment: No. I want a switch that makes `devtools::test()` behave **as though it were running on CRAN** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still have this question but I put this line at the top of my first test file and it works in R 4.2.1.

```
Sys.setenv(NOT_CRAN='skip')
```